# ruby on rails only load 1 css & js file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am new to `ruby on rails` and whenever i create and `access` a `controller` i can see it loads a new `css & js` file with name as the name of the controller...

How can i make it load only **1** `css and js` file called `style.css` and `site.js` for example?

what is the purpose of having multiple `js & css` files whenever i access a contrller?

if i go to `application.html.erb` and change

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

to

```
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag("application") %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag("application") %>
```

it doesnt seem to help

Comment: In development mode files never compiled for debug purposes. In production they are compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

will include all `.css` and `.js` files available in `assets/javascripts/` and `assets/stylesheets/`. So, if you want to include only the `style.css` and `site.js` just remove everything else.

Your `assets/javascripts/` should have only the `application.js` and `site.js`.

And your `assets/stylesheets/` should have the `application.css` and `style.css`.

**EDIT**

`` `application.js `` and `application.css` are part of the [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline).

You can disable it if you want by adding this line in your `application.rb`

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

You can also change the `application.html.erb` to include only your `style.css` and `site.js`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "style", :media => "all" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "site" %>
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: whats the difference on those 2 js files and css files? can i have only site.css and site.js? or its required to have both?

Comment: It is recommended to have both: "You should use the defaults for all new applications unless you have a specific reason to avoid the asset pipeline" ([Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-the-asset-pipeline)), but I have edited my answer to you :)

Answer (score 2):

I dont know which Rails version you are using, but assuming it is the recent one, then Rails are using Assets Pipeline, to merge multiple files and serve all css / javascript files compressed / merged.

You can learn more about it at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Basically what you do is, you reference one file 'application' (css or js) and inside this file, you customize which files it should include.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `:cache => 'cache-display'`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all, :cache => 'cache/display' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :all, :cache => 'cache/display' %>
```